# Getting session id through redirect in Python

Tags: python, http, session, cookies, https

First of all, my programming background is mostly limited to server side scripting and this is pretty much the first time I'm trying to parse a website so please forgive me if my question is ridiculous.

I am trying to pull some data from a website (battlefield.com) which requires authentication through another site.

I have a following script:

```
import requests

url_login = "https://signin.ea.com/p/web/login?execution=e1567523006s1&initref=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.ea.com%3A443%2Fconnect%2Fauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.battlefield.com%252Flogin_check%26state%3D5223dcd1-5f9c-47a1-940c-1d6b306454f9%26response_type%3Dcode%26client_id%3DBattlefield-CoreWeb"

url_bf = "https://www.battlefield.com/companion/career/mypersonalid/bf1"

s = requests.Session()

payload = {
    "username": "myemail",
    "password": "mypassword"
}

req1 = s.post(url_login, data=payload)

req2 = s.get(url_bf)

print (s.cookies)
```

When I do this process manually, I go to battlefield.com, click sign in and then the page redirects me to the `url_login` page.
Then I post the payload and the page redirects me back to the battlefield page.

What I am trying to do is to get the sessionID from the battlefield page after logging in successfully.

The output of the script above is (modified the sessionid and removed tags):

```
RequestsCookieJar[Cookie ealocale=en-us for .battlefield.com/, Cookie JSESSIONID=1DF14B ... 3DAF.eanshprdaccounts38 for signin.ea.com/p/]
```

But I don't think this sessionID is correct. When I manually check the `sessionID` using Chrome Inspector from the battlefield.com page after logging in, the name of the session appears to be different and it has a completely different value:

[image: Screenshot]

So my question is, how can I get the `BTLF_SESSID`?

Thank you in advance

Comment: check your request status codes, also may be worth trying `requests.get('http://...', allow_redirects=False)` and inspecting those responses from the sign-in service

Comment: @user3012759 The result is the same, even with allow_redirects=False

Comment: @user3012759 The response codes are req1: 302, req2: 200.
But the response for req1 is 302 even though I enter invalid credentials and clear cookies... I don't understand

Comment: ok, so the 302, where does it redirect you to? is it always the same url? it's possible that you're being redirected back to your bf page but with a auth token that bf page understand, and in your code you don't actually pass this token on as you have bf address hardcoded so you will not be authenticated

Comment: @user3012759 There is a redirect uri in the login url:
`www.battlefield.com%252Flogin_check%26state`.
Ok, so I will try to figure out how to enter the page after the login is successful.

Answer (score 1):

How funny. I was just looking at this too.

Instead of having a static url_login try using a redirect so the execution variable is set. I'm not sure if this is needed but it seems like a safe bet.

Then you can reference the url in the response for your login POST.

I'm also sending all of the form data from the login page, not just username and password.

And then GET the auth.json

```
s = requests.Session()

init_url = 'https://www.battlefield.com/login?postAuthUri=/companion'
auth_json = 'https://www.battlefield.com/service/auth.json'

init = s.get(init_url)

login_payload = {
    'rememberMe': 'on', 
    '_rememberMe': 'on', 
    'gCaptchaResponse': '', 
    '_eventId': 'submit', 
    'password': password
    'email': email
    }

ea_login = s.post(init.url, data=login_payload)

auth = s.get(auth_json)
```

After that last step if you look at auth.json() you should see a payload with your gamertag, pid, age, and authenticated = True.

I think there's still some additional steps after this to actually get your stats. Just start from your that first url in chrome with the devtools open and look at what its doing under the Network table (filter by XHR). Also there are IDs generated for each json request and a `X-GatewaySession` ID that is generated the same way but initialized earlier and it looks like it needs to be saved for future requests. Look in the init.js file to see how those are generated.

Also, for your original question about the `BTLF_SESSID`. That's just a unique session identifier, it will be different between your browser and python because they're different sessions. And I think you can ignore it, the requests session will take care of passing that data to the server on its own.

Comment: Yes, the X-GatewaySession is the only issue I have left. I do not know how to get it. I've been looking through the page with devtools in Chrome and I'm stuck to the api?Companion.IsLoggedIn part.
There seems to be two IsLoggedIn's, and in the first part the X-GateWaySession is not present. But suddenly it appears on the second part.
I've managed to get the X-GatewayTraceID, but I don't know if it's related in any way...
But everything works if I fetch the sessionid manually, thanks to your code!

Comment: Ok, finally got it. The sessionID came through accounts.ea, and I needed the auth token for that. After passing this token to the API: Companion.loginFromAuthCode, it gave me the sessionID.

Thank you for help!